# Flask_login problem with user_loader() function giving me None

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I am currently making project for a course and I am not allowed to use ORM in my Flask app, so I created my own class with methods querying the sql with db.session.execute() commands.

My problem is that when "@login_manager.user_loader" tries to get the user_id, it fails because the id is "None".
I don't understand the following:

1. when and where "user_loader" tries to check with user_id
2. what does user_id refer to or its value
3. why isn't user_id getting the value id from the user class I created at the login app.route.

**Note:** if I change what I am searching for from id to username the code works and the website works fine,
 **but** `current_user.is_authenticated:` doesn't work and I can keep on logging in as many times as I want even with different user accounts.

My app is currently packaged with the following file tree:

[image: Package File Tree]

This is the code snippet for the User Class in models.py:

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.searchwo(id=user_id)

class User(UserMixin):

    def __init__(self, username, password=None, id=None):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.id = id

    def create(self):
        db.session.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)", {"username": self.username, "password": self.password})
        db.session.commit()

    def search(self):
        response = db.session.execute("SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username", {"username":self.username}).fetchone()
        if response != None:
            self.id = response[0]
            self.password = response[2]
        return response

    @staticmethod
    def searchwo(id=None, username=None):
        if id != None:
            response = db.session.execute("SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE id = :id", {"id":id}).fetchone()
        elif username != None:
            response = db.session.execute("SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username", {"username":username}).fetchone()
        return response
```

This is the login code snippet in routes.py:

where I create a user object class at "user = User(....."

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        usertemp = User.searchwo(username=form.username.data)
        if usertemp == None:
            user = None
        else:
            user = User(usertemp[1], password=usertemp[2])
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('main'))
        else:
            flash('Invalid credentials! if your not a user please register first.')
    return render_template('index.html', title='Book Reviews', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out how to solve my problem by creating @classmethod.
I am new to python so I didn't yet reach @classmethod in my study. 
But by creating a @classmethod I was able to properly return the object type that `user_loader` normally returns, instead of the tuple type I was returning in the original code.
This is the @classmethod I created at the end of the User class:

```py
    @classmethod
    def searchid(cls, id):
        response = db.session.execute("SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE id = :id", {"id":id}).fetchone()
        return cls(response[1], response[2], response[0])

    @classmethod
    def searchuser(cls, username):
        response = db.session.execute("SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username", {"username":username}).fetchone()
        return cls(response[1], response[2], response[0])
```

This is how the user_loader looks like now:

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.searchid(id=user_id)
```

From what I understood while debugging my app while creating the @classmethod is that (to answer my questions):

1. The `user_loader` performs its checks at the checking and whenever I am redirected or the page refreshed.
2. The `user_id` gets its value from the user class object created at the login route which it gets from the user input in the login form.
3. The `user_id` wasn't getting the value because I forgot to update the User class object with the ID after checking the credentials at the login app.route. This means that I might have been able to solve the problem without creating @classmethod (not sure of this though).

Please do correct me if my understanding of the 3 points is incorrect.